# Query for Select Id,name,Cost on Delivery using sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make one query for selecting `customer id`, `cus_name`, `Total COD Orders`. I made these two queries ,but these queries calculating the `COD` and `NON COD` separately. How I make a single query using sub query.

```
SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name), count(o.order_no) AS 'Total COD Orders'
FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c INNER JOIN
     T_Inv_Order o
     ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1 AND o.cod = 1
GROUP BY o.cust_id, c.name;

SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name), count(o.order_no) AS 'Total COD Orders'
FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c INNER JOIN
     T_Inv_Order o
     ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1 AND o.cod = 0
GROUP BY o.cust_id, c.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.cust_id, 
       UPPER(c.name), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.cod = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total COD Orders',
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.cod = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total non COD Orders' 
FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c
INNER JOIN T_Inv_Order o ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1
group by o.cust_id, c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

As the queries seem to be very similar you could use a `union`. So your queries become:

```
SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name), count(o.order_no) AS 'Total COD Orders' FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c
INNER JOIN T_Inv_Order o ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1 AND o.cod = 1
group by o.cust_id, c.name

UNION

SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name), count(o.order_no) AS 'Total COD Orders' FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c
INNER JOIN T_Inv_Order o ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1 AND o.cod = 0

group by o.cust_id, c.name
```

This will comebine the two queries into one results set. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp for more information on the Union keyword.

Comment: I am trying this your UNOIN in the code as you described ,but this is giving the error as listed below : "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'T_Inv_Order.cust_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: I made an edit that included the first group by as I accidentally missed it off. Have you tried it with the group by in both sections of the select?

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name),
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.cod = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalCODOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.cod = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalNonCODOrders
FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c INNER JOIN
     T_Inv_Order o
     ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1
GROUP BY o.cust_id, c.name;
```

If `o.cod` only takes on the values 0 and 1, then you can use the short-cut:

```
SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name),
       SUM(o.cod = 1) as TotalCODOrders,
       SUM(1 - o.cod) as TotalNonCODOrders,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Union**

```
SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name), count(o.order_no) AS 'Total COD Orders'
FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c INNER JOIN
     T_Inv_Order o
     ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1 AND o.cod = 1
GROUP BY o.cust_id, c.name;

UNION

SELECT o.cust_id, UPPER(c.name), count(o.order_no) AS 'Total COD Orders'
FROM T_Acct_CompanyProfile c INNER JOIN
     T_Inv_Order o
     ON c.id = o.cust_id
WHERE c.type_id = 1 AND o.cod = 0
GROUP BY o.cust_id, c.name;
```

Comment: i'd use union all since you don't want a distinct and i'd add `o.cod` to be able to see which count is which